# cant post value using ajax in zend framework 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

I'm using ajax to post a value as given below,
but data I post wont reach the controllers `ajaxAaction`

**view script** (which is a tpl file)

```
<input type="text" id='taska'>
<button id='submitTo'>button</button>
```

**script**

```
 $(document).ready(
    function(){

       //controller via ajax
        $("#submitTo").click(function() {  
              var message = $('#taska').val(); 

              if (message != '') { 
                  //run ajax 
                  //alert ('not empty');
                  $.post('index/ajax', 
                            {'message' : message}, 

                            //callback function
                            function (respond) {

                                 //put respond in class show-msg

                                 $(".show-msg").html(respond);                  

                     }
                  );
              } 

        });
```

and the **action**

```
 public function ajaxAction() {
       //get post request (standart approach) 

       $request = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

       //referring to the index
       //gets value from ajax request 
       $message = $request['message'];

      // makes disable renderer
      $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

      //makes disable layout
      $this->_helper->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();

     //return callback message to the function javascript
     echo $message;
}


  } );
```

`$.post('index/ajax',` is the part where I think the error is.

Am I defining the controller and action in the wrong way?
I've been stuck here for a while.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with `$this->basePath()` in  `<?php echo $this->basePath();?>index/ajax`

Comment: sorry, it doesn't help :(

Comment: ok then check in firebug where the form is submitting the data.

Comment: Firebug does say the action does not exist,but it does !

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by prefixing the `rootPath` as below

```
  if (message != '') { 
                  //run ajax  rootPath
                {/literal}  $.post("{eval var=$rootPath}/index/ajax", {literal}
                            {'message' : message}, 

                            //callback function
                            function (respond) {
```